# Kendo Window using Twitter Bootstrap UI

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, kendo-ui, kendo-window

Is there a way to invoke the Kendo window and have the window UI be the default modal for bootstrap rather than the default Kendo Window. I want the window to look like a modal in bootstrap, rather than a window from kendo. Obviously I can do this with customize the window with css, just trying to determine if that is the only path.

Comment: I suggest not to do that. It's the pain in the ass to maintain styles if something changes in bootstrap or kendo ui.

Comment: @japi We're using local copies, so that isn't an issue. More to the question was that did something like this come out of the box, or is the answer custom css.

Comment: Haven't never tried this. As far as I know, Kendo does not provide any custom styling for this so I guess it's just hacking Kendo css.